# Testing AngularJS with Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I am trying to test the AngularJS tutorial (http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app) with PhantomJS. I cannot get typing in a search to actually run.

Here is what I am at so far:

```
var page = new WebPage();
page.open('http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app', function() {
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        $("[ng-model=query]").click();
        $("[ng-model=query]").focus();
        $("[ng-model=query]").val("xoom");
        console.log($('ul.phones').text());
    });
    phantom.exit()
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding doesn't seem to work when directly changing the input value. You would need to use PhantomJS' native input method [`sendEvent`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html).

```
page.open('http://angular.github.io/angular-phonecat/step-7/app', function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
        document.querySelector('[ng-model=query]').focus();
    });
    page.sendEvent("keypress", "xoom");
    page.evaluate(function() {
        console.log(document.querySelectorAll('ul.phones li').length + " products");
    });
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: I had to do a bit of work to separate when the functions were executed but page.sendEvent("keypress", "xoom"); did the trick!

Comment: How to proceed when the element to interact with is a select? This method unfortunately doesn't work...

Comment: @Puce Focus on the `select` element and `page.sendEvent("keypress", page.event.key.Down);` as much as you need. I think Fanch has mentioned this method with selects last year.

Comment: Thanks! I made it work with this: `$(".select#selectId").val(selectedValue).trigger('change');`